# Can I export data from one component to update a state in a Parent of a Parent?

Tags: reactjs, api, components, state

I would like to send the variable "synonym", which I have collected in this event, to another component. The component is not directly linked to this one, it is in fact a parent of a parent.

Ideally, this word will update the state on the other component so I can run the API again, with this new word.

```
export default function Synonym(props) {
  function searchSynonym(event) {
    let synonym = event.target.innerHTML;
  }

  if (props.synonyms.length > 0) {
    return (
      <div className="Synonym">
        {props.synonyms.map((word, index) => {
          if (index < 10) {
            return (
              <button
                key={index}
                className="synonym-word"
                onClick={searchSynonym}
              >
                {word}
              </button>
            );
          } else return null;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  } else return null;
}
```

Full code is open-sources on [GitHub](https://github.com/mariaalouisaa/Dictionary-Project). The component I am trying to send word to is Search.js

**Thank you in advance**, I'm very new to React!

Comment: You can use callback props, context API or state management libraries like redux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The processes for passing data from a child component to a parent component are as follows:

- Create a callback function in the parent component. The data will be
  retrieved from the child component using this callback function.
- As a prop from the parent component, pass the callback function to
  the child.
- Using props, the child component calls the parent callback function
  and return data to the parent component.

In your situation
The straightforward and simple solution is to create a callback function in the Search component that you want to use the "Synonym" and then pass the function as a prop to the Definitions component and then pass it to the Synonym component again.

like the following!

In Search Component create a synonym useState and create getSynonym callback function the pass it as prop to the Definitions component.

```
export default function Search() {
  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState("");
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null);
  const [photos, setPhotos] = useState(null);
  const [synonym, setSynonym] = useState(null);
  const getSynonym = (value) =>{
    setSynonym(value)
  }

  {....}

  return (
    <div className="Search">
      <form onSubmit={handleSearch}>
        <input className="input" type="search" onChange={updateCity} />
      </form>
      <Definitions data={result} getSynonym={getSynonym}/>
      <Pictures data={photos} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

In Definations component pass callback function to the Synonym component again.

```
 export default function Definitions(props) {
     {...}    
        return (
          {...}
          <Synonym synonyms={meaning.definitions[0].synonyms} getSynonym={props.getSynonym} />
          {...}
        );
    }
```

In Synonym component calls the callback function.

```
export default function Synonym(props) {
  function searchSynonym(event) {
    let synonym = event.target.innerHTML;
    props.getSynonym(synonym)
  }
{...}
}
```